# Yii: Firebug console ( function isn't defined ) when registering a function using clientscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

When I define a function in Yii view

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('jqeury5', 
   "function fn(){ alert('hello'); }"
 );
```

then try to call it, the Firebug says the "fn isn't defined" when I press on button.

```
<input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds"
onclick="fn()" />
```

Comment: you seem to have a syntax error in the script -
"funciton fn() { alert('hello');}"
you don't need the extra ");"

Comment: hey, have you checked my solution? if you don't mind, please gimme some feedback. i'd like to know how it worked for you, or if you were expecting something else. AFAIK it should work, it's tested!

Comment: @mukeshSoni , ah sorry it's just typo in here when I wrote the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the function in the `<head>` part, or `<body>` part of the html document that is generated. Use the third parameter of the `registerScript()` function.
So your code will be:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('jqeury5', "
    function fn(){
        alert('hello');
    }",CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

For more details read the [api documentation here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail).

P.S: i think by default the script is inserted in jQuery's `ready` function. Hence the function is not detected.

Comment: let me know if you need any clarifications